# How would I make a door open when a key is pressed and a character is near?

Tags: animation, game-engine, objects

I am trying to make a door open for a game i'm making using the blender game engine, i have the animations set up for the door, I have everything set up for the door to activate yet nothing happens. How would I get this to work.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your .blend and as you said everything is set up correctly.
But the 'Near' sensor only gets activated by "Actors" (this is a physic 'property') so you need to go to the physic tap of your character (Cube) and actiate Actor.

[image]

Comment: That worked in the test file, but for some reason when i try it in game with all the same settings it does nothing

Comment: i've uploaded a better representation of the problem

Comment: I tried it again. The only problem is the distance in teh NEAR Sensor. it is set to a soo small value. I Changed it to two or three and it worked.

Comment: There we go, thanks. idk why the range is different between objects with static and dynamic physics but problem solved